# Cannot create odoo-8(openerp) service in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: service, ubuntu-16.04, odoo-8, odoo

I want to create an odoo instance version 8 in ubuntu 16.
Config and service files are created, i am adding permission of files below.

- drwxr-xr-x  6 root root      4096 May 24 18:40 .
- drwxr-xr-x  3 sic  sic       4096 May 24 17:40 ..
- drwxr-xr-x  8 sic  sic       4096 Apr 11 08:54 odoo
- -rw-r--r--  1 root root 319123456 May 24 18:38 odoo_sic.tar
- drwxrwxrwx 23 sic  sic       4096 May 24 17:40 orchid_addons
- drwxrwxrwx  9 sic  sic       4096 May 24 17:40 orchid_excel_reports

Config file:
 - -rw-r-----   1 sic    sic     311 May 25 10:12 001-sic-live-server.conf

Init file:
 - -rwxr-xr-x   1 sic  sic  2219 May 25 10:16 001-sic-live-server

when i try to start the service log file is not created, also no ***service started*** message

Answer (score 2):

Follow My steps:

1 Create conf file

```
sudo nano /etc/odoo8.conf
```

2 Create conf file data

```
[options]
admin_passwd = your_strong_admin_password
db_host = False
db_port = False
db_user = odoo8
db_password = False
addons_path = /opt/odoo8/addons
logfile = /var/log/odoo8.log
xmlrpc_port = 8010
```

3 Create service

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/odoo8.service
```

4

```
[Unit]
Description=Odoo 8
Requires=postgresql.service
After=postgresql.service

[Service]
Type=simple
PermissionsStartOnly=true
User=odoo8
Group=odoo8
SyslogIdentifier=odoo8
ExecStart=/opt/odoo8/venv/bin/python2 /opt/odoo8/odoo-bin -c /etc/odoo8.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then enable service.

```
sudo systemctl enable odoo8.service
```

Comment: Thanks Burmese i wil check and tell